# How can I disable/modify the SSH login banner for a given user?

Tags: command-line, ssh

How can I disable/modify the SSH login banner for a given user?

[image]

Comment: I think it is located at /etc/motd. Try editing that file and see

Comment: I did edit it but the changes are always overwritten by this default message.

Comment: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-change-message-of-the-day-motd-in-ubuntu-server.html says there is /etc/motd.tail file you should edit for ubuntu server.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It seems it is possible to disable this message on a user basis by creating an empty file in a user's $HOME directory (/home/username/) called `.hushlogin`.

```
touch ~/.hushlogin
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this is performed on the system that sends the banner. Not the one that receives it.

Comment: This does not override a `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` Banner

Answer (score 21):

If you want to disable that message for all ssh users, edit `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and comment out the lines

```
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
session    optional     pam_motd.so # [1]
```

Comment: Works on ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 13):

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` make sure there is a line:

```
PrintMotd no
```

If it is set to 'yes' change it to 'no'.

Restart the SSH server by typing

```
service ssh restart
```

You should be good to go from there.

Comment: +1 Your solution is great because it keeps Last login but hides the rest.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. At least not in 14.04. Mine was already set `"no"` and yet the welcome greeting was still showing. What helped was updating `/etc/pam.d/sshd`.

Comment: @cherio , I can confirm that the same worked for me. Using LTS 14.04

Comment: No longer applies to 14.04, see @cweiske's answer as it does work for 14.04.

Comment: Does not work on 16.04

Answer (score 4):

It is also possible to disable banner using client-side only solution, that is by setting log level to error:

```
ssh -o LogLevel=Error <rest of cmd>
```

Found here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/how-do-you-turn-off-login-banner-for-non-interactive-ssh-470516/

Comment: This is the answer, if you don't have sudo access to turn off the Banner on the remote machine.

Answer (score 3):

`.hushlogin` didn't do the trick for me (on Debian 7), but setting Banner to `/dev/null` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` :

```
#Banner /etc/issue.net
Banner /dev/null
```